# How to increase the size of a curly bracket size without \left and \right

Tags: delimiters, braces

I would like to ask how to increase the dimension of the curly bracket in the second item of the following list:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Draw $\tilde{\theta}$ from $j$
\item Calculate $\nu = \min \{ {\frac{p(\theta^{k}+\tilde{\theta})}{p(\theta^{k})},1} \}$
\item With probability of $\nu$, put $\theta^{k+1}=\theta^{k}+\tilde{\theta}$, otherwise put $\theta^{k+1}= \theta$
\end{enumerate}
```

I tried by adding `\left{` and `\right}` as follows

```
\item Calculate $\nu = \min \left{ {\frac{p(\theta^{k}+\tilde{\theta})}{p(\theta^{k})},1} \right}$
```

but I still receive an error message.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with suggestions in this respect.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Use `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

Comment: What Alex said.  Since braces are special characters in TeX, they need to be 'escaped' *wherever* they occur.  @Alex, I'd post that as the answer.

Comment: @Alex Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Curly braces are special characters in TeX. To print them, they need to be escaped with a backslash (as you did in the first code fragment). The same holds for combinations with `\left`/`\right`, or `\big` and so on, i.e., you should use `\left\{` and `\right\}`.